# glsl texture access synchronization, openCL vs glsl image processing

Tags: c++, opengl, parallel-processing, glsl, opencl

This might be a trivial question. 
I am curious about how glsl would synchronize when accessing texture data via a fragment shader. 
Say I have a code like below in a fragment shader.

```
void main() {
    vec3 texCoord = in_texCoord;
    vec4 out_voxel_intensity = texture(image, vec3(texCoord.x , texCoord.y, texCoord.z));
    out_voxel = float(out_voxel_intensity) ;
    if(out_voxel <= threshold)
    {
        out_voxel = 0.0;
        return;
    }
    for(int i = -int(kernalSize); i <= int(kernalSize);++i)
        for(int j = -int(kernalSize); j <= int(kernalSize); ++j)
            for(int k = -int(kernalSize); k <= int(kernalSize); ++k)
            {
                float x_o = texCoord.x + i / (imageSize.x);
                float y_o = texCoord.y + j / (imageSize.y);
                float z_o = texCoord.z + k / (imageSize.z);
                if(x_o < 0.0 || x_o > 1.0
                    || y_o  < 0. || y_o > 1.0
                    || z_o  < 0. || z_o  > 1.0)
                    continue;
                if(float(texture(image, vec3(x_o, y_o, z_o))) <= threshold)
                {
                    out_voxel = 0.0;
                    return;
                }

            }
}
```

as the code above access not only the current texture coordinate, but the values around it with the specified kernel size, how glsl takes care that no other parallel process access the same texture coordinates. 
W.r.t that question, does the code above performs efficiently in a fragment shader given it access neighboring texture data or using openCL better?
Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're only reading from the texture in your example. There's absolutely no problem with multiple shader instances reading with the same texture coordinates at the same time. Synchronization considerations only come into play when you write to textures from the shader.

Comment: so textures are cached by each shader instance?

Comment: @code_not_yet_complete: "*so textures are cached by each shader instance?*" Does it matter? The data *has not changed*, so there is nothing to synchronize.